# How can we pass List<Text> as Mapper output?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a problem of Map-Reduce. But I stuck at one point that how can I pass `List<Text>` as `Mapper output`? Is it possible or not? If yes, then how can we tell the `configuration` about the `Mapper output class`?

Answer (score 6):

You may use the [ArrayWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html) class as value object from your mapper class. Please refer the below code snippet for your mapper class,

```
ArrayWritable arrayWritable = new ArrayWritable(Text.class);

Text [] textValues = new Text[2];
textValues[0] = new Text("value1");
textValues[1] = new Text("value1");

arrayWritable.set(textValues );
context.write(key , arrayWritable );
```

set the value class as following in your driver class,

```
job.setMapOutputValueClass(ArrayWritable.class);
```